# Error: Could Not Serialize Object of Type "FireStore"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run a Firebase function that simply adds a string to a database document (saving product to shopping cart). The action does not complete and I get an interesting error message.

```
const cartItem = "Product name"

firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addToCart')({ cartItem })
```

And in my functions index.js:

```
exports.addToCart = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const userID = context.auth.uid
    cartItem = data.cartItem
    const cartDoc = db.doc(`/carts/${userID}`)
    cartDoc.set({
        ...cartDoc,
        items: [cartItem]
    })

})
```

And this is my error message in the Firebase console:

```
Unhandled error Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "Firestore" (found in field "_firestore"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).
    at Object.validateUserInput (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:301:15)
    at validateDocumentData (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:620:22)
    at WriteBatch.set (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:234:9)
    at DocumentReference.set (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:340:14)
    at exports.addToCart.functions.https.onCall (/srv/index.js:258:13)
    at func (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:267:32)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

It says that it can't serialize object of type "Firestore" found in field "_firestore". I find this quite arcane. Also, this syntax works perfectly fine in other functions I have that write to database documents. I have tried passing the string directly i.e. `('addToCart')('Product_Name')` and I've also tried explicitly stating the prototype, as I saw that in other posts, i.e. `({cartItem: 'Product_Name', __proto__: Object})` and I've also tried updating my dependencies.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code makes no sense at all:

```
const cartDoc = db.doc(`/carts/${userID}`)
cartDoc.set({
    ...cartDoc,
    items: [cartItem]
})
```

if you want to set the document based on its current field values, you'll need to `get()` that document first, and then set its `data()` back to the database.

But there's no need to load the document data if you just want to update a field. Instead you can update it with:

```
cartDoc.update({ items: [cartItem] })
```

---

If the `items` field is an array that you want to add the new item to, you'll want to [use an `arrayUnion`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) instead, like this:

```
cartDoc.update({ items: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(cartItem) })
```